# Typo3 Flow which RTE?

Tags: rte, typo3-flow

For a Typo3 Flow 2.1.2 Projekt we are looking for a stable RTE. We would also be ready to pay a licence if there are good arguments :)

What are your suggestions?
Which RTE do you use with your Flow projects?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you build some tailor-made app and you're going to incorporate RTE there for that app neeeds.

You might go the route TYPO3 Neos went: it uses [Aloha Editor](http://www.aloha-editor.org/). TYPO3 Neos, as I'm sure you know, is an application (very powerful CMS in fact) build on top of TYPO3 Flow - seems like similar case.

On the other side, I'm not sure if the Flow has anything to say here - you can pick up any RTE and embed it there, as you'll have to do it anyway. You probably could evaluate best available RTE (eg. CKEditor, TinyMCE, now sure what else is there) and pick up the one which best suits your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes we use a "good" RTE for our app. I was looking for someone who already embedded a RTE and maybe already did a small evaluation about the available rte's.